# Control formula to ensure all filtered data is correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vba

I am using an advanced filter where based on a selection, I get a list of data (can be large amount of data).

Within that list of data, I have email addresses in column "AI" from cell 18 to however long the data filetered is. Because this list of emails is used for notification, I need to make sure there are all correct and that I have no N/A or error. I have this formula that I am using at the moment:

{=IF(SUM(IF(ISNA(AI18:AI29),1,IF(AI18:AI29="",1,0)))>0,"Error column AI","Yes")}

The formula above does what in need but it stops at cell 29. I don't want to have to manually change the length of the formula. I have been trying to incorporate MAX into it but it does not seem to work.

Question: I need the 29 in this formula to go up or down based on the result of the advance filter.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is specify a variable range. This can be done with the OFFSET function. If you replace the range `AI18:AI29` with `OFFSET(AI18,0,0,FILTER_RESULT,1)` you should get what you are looking for. Where `FILTER_RESULT` is the height of the range. In the case of 29 it would be a height of 11.

```
OFFSET(
   reference cell: The base cell to refer to.
   rows: The number of rows, up or down, that you want the upper-left cell to refer to.
   cols: The number of columns, to the left or right, that you want the upper-left cell of the result to refer to.
   height: The height of the range you want
   width: The width of the range you want
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from but it does not work. I tried  =(IF(SUM(IF(ISNA(OFFSET(AI18,0,0,FILTER_RESULT,1)),1,IF(OFFSET(AI18,0,0,FILTER_RESULT,1)="",1,0)))>0,"Error column AI","Yes"))

Comment: It could be because I am using an advanced filter. Your formula suggested above remains on cell AI18. I am trying to find a way now.

Comment: From your question I assumed you'd only want the 18 changing. It's easy enough to get the base to change as well. For example you could have the base start at AI1 then just have the rows parameter indicate what row the range start at.

Comment: Check what range the offset formula is selecting compared with what range you want it to select. It should be an easy fix regardless.